# How can I use transport_map without a existing alias or user in Postfix?

Tags: postfix, smtp

I'am searching for a way to bypass some accounts to a diffrent Mailserver then postfix. So some accounts should exist on the postfix server but anything else should be transport to a second SMTP Server. For that I setup a new centos 7 and install postfix with yum install postfix. In the defaultconfig I add transport_maps and for a simple test I add example.com in transport_maps with the destination Mailserver. But in case I send a Mail to userX@example.com postfix told me the account doesnet exist.

Postfix only accept Mails for known user so I create a alias in /etc/aliases userX: trash and the Mail will be transport to the destination SMTP Server. My Issue is that I do not know all the aliases from the Destination SMTP Server so I cant add all aliases to aliases.db is there a Option to accept all user on postfix for a known domain?

For a trivial example I need to transport all user to a diffrent SMTP Server.

```
#postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, example.com
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

And my /etc/postfix/transport looks like:

```
example.com smtp:smtp.local
```

**UPDATE**
As mentioned below I try to solve the issue with `fallback_transport`. I had updated my main.cf with

```
fallback_transport = relay
fallback_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

and the content of `/etc/postfix/transport` is

```
example.com smtp:smtp.local
*           smtp:smtp.local
```

but with this config the issue is the same. The user doestn exist so postfix told me the user doesnt exist. If I delete the example.com URL from mydestination the behavior is that the mail to user@example.com is in the mailq

Answer (score 1):

You have to use either `fallback_transport` or `luser_relay`.

From: http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html

> fallback_transport (default: empty)
>
> Optional message delivery transport that the local(8) delivery agent should use for names that are not found in the aliases(5) or UNIX password database.
>
> luser_relay (default: empty)
>
> Optional catch-all destination for unknown local(8) recipients. By default, mail for unknown recipients in domains that match
>   $mydestination, $inet_interfaces or $proxy_interfaces is returned as
>   undeliverable.

To consider:

> The precedence of local(8) delivery features from high to low is:
>   aliases, .forward files, mailbox_transport_maps, mailbox_transport,
>   mailbox_command_maps, mailbox_command, home_mailbox,
>   mail_spool_directory, fallback_transport_maps, fallback_transport and
>   luser_relay.

Comment: With luser_realy I only can send all mails to a specific user as I understood and with fallback_transport I doesnt work. For fallback_transport = relay and fallback_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport with entry example.com smtp:smtp.local the Mail will reject only if I delete example.com from mydestination. And If deleted from mydestination the mail wont relay to smtp.local but is still in the mailq. I update the question with the config

Comment: http://postfix.1071664.n5.nabble.com/Setting-Up-FallBack-Transport-td59754.html This seems to suggest you need to use `virtual_alias_maps` and explicitly define each user in the local server and then a catch-all address that gets rewritten to the domain of the second server. If that domain is not publicly routable you will have to define it in `transport_maps`. Not sure if there's a better solution.

Comment: Yes, that's the way I do for now. But with virtual_alias_maps I need to know all the aliases, that's difficult but not impossible. The Way to use a fallback relay would be much better because I know exactly all the User for the postfix system.

Comment: Just tried it using `luser_relay = $user@example2.com` and `local_recipient_maps = `. Any user that doesn't exist in the local server (after aliasing) gets redirected to `example2.com`. Is this what you need?